Проблема с ничьей в боте
У меня есть телеграм бот и это карточная игра про бойцов ufs в котором все работает корректно, но там немного неправильно работает система ничьи, а именно она одного игрока просит подождать пока другой кинет карту после того как тот кидает карту она показывает ее тому кто ждал, но это неправильно! надо чтобы это работало вот так: 1 - после того как произошла ничья в новом раунде обеим игрокам выводятся их карты и клавиатура, после чего они делают свой ход. 2 - после хода они должны видеть результат сражения, и карточку противника, НО ОНИ ДОЛЖНЫ ВИДИТ КАРТУ ПРОТИВНИКА ТОЛЬКО ПОСЛЕ ТОГО КАК ПОЛУЧАТ РЕЗУЛЬТАТ СРАЖЕНИЯ, надеюсь я понятно объяснил
async def start_duel(user1_id, user2_id):
    try:
        user1_cards = duel_data[user1_id]["remaining_cards"]
        user2_cards = duel_data[user2_id]["remaining_cards"]
        print(f"Карты пользователя {user1_id}: {[card.id for card in user1_cards]}")  # Логирование
        print(f"Карты пользователя {user2_id}: {[card.id for card in user2_cards]}")  # Логирование

        duel_data[user1_id]["current_cards"] = user1_cards
        duel_data[user2_id]["current_cards"] = user2_cards

        if duel_data[user1_id]["round"] == 1:
            await send_card_group(user1_id, user1_cards)
            await send_card_group(user2_id, user2_cards)
            await bot.send_message(user1_id, "Выберите карту для битвы:",
                                   reply_markup=await kb.get_card_keyboard([card.id for card in user1_cards]))
            await bot.send_message(user2_id, "Выберите карту для битвы:",
                                   reply_markup=await kb.get_card_keyboard([card.id for card in user2_cards]))
        else:
            current_user = user1_id if duel_data[user1_id]["first"] else user2_id
            current_cards = user1_cards if duel_data[user1_id]["first"] else user2_cards

            await send_card_group(current_user, current_cards)
            await bot.send_message(current_user, "Выберите карту для битвы:",
                                   reply_markup=await kb.get_card_keyboard([card.id for card in current_cards]))

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Ошибка в start_duel: {e}")


@user.callback_query(lambda c: c.data.startswith("select_card_"))
async def on_card_selected(callback_query: CallbackQuery):
    try:
        card_id = int(callback_query.data.split("_")[2])
        user_id = callback_query.from_user.id
        print(f"Пользователь {user_id} выбрал карту {card_id}")  # Логирование
        card = await get_card_by_id(card_id)

        # Обновление состояния игрока
        duel_data[user_id]["selected_card"] = card
        duel_data[user_id]["remaining_cards"] = [c for c in duel_data[user_id]["remaining_cards"] if c.id != card_id]

        await bot.send_photo(user_id, card.image_url, caption="Карта которую выбрал ты")

        opponent_id = duel_data[user_id]["opponent"]

        # Удаляем сообщение с кнопками после выбора карты
        await bot.delete_message(user_id, callback_query.message.message_id)

        # Проверяем, выбрал ли противник карту только если нет ничьей
        if duel_data[opponent_id]["selected_card"] is None and duel_data[user_id]["selected_card"] is not None:
            if duel_data[user_id]["round"] > 1:
                await bot.send_photo(opponent_id, card.image_url,
                                     caption=f"Ваш соперник выбрал карту: {card.name} (Атака: {card.attack}, Защита: {card.defense}). Теперь ваша очередь выбрать карту.")
                await send_card_group(opponent_id, duel_data[opponent_id]["remaining_cards"])
                await bot.send_message(opponent_id, "Выберите карту",
                                       reply_markup=await kb.get_card_keyboard(
                                           [c.id for c in duel_data[opponent_id]["remaining_cards"]]))
        else:
            await determine_winner(user_id, opponent_id)

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Ошибка в on_card_selected: {e}")



async def handle_winner(winner_id, loser_id, winner_card):
    duel_data[winner_id]["score"] += 1
    duel_data[winner_id]["round_wins"] += 1
    duel_data[winner_id]["first"] = True
    duel_data[loser_id]["first"] = False

    await bot.send_message(winner_id, "⭐️ Вы выиграли раунд!")
    await bot.send_message(loser_id, " Вы проиграли раунд!")


async def determine_winner(user1_id, user2_id):
    try:
        user1_card = duel_data[user1_id]["selected_card"]
        user2_card = duel_data[user2_id]["selected_card"]

        user1_attack = int(user1_card.attack)
        user1_defense = int(user1_card.defense)
        user2_attack = int(user2_card.attack)
        user2_defense = int(user2_card.defense)

        if user1_attack > user2_defense:
            await handle_winner(user1_id, user2_id, user1_card)
        elif user2_attack > user1_defense:
            await handle_winner(user2_id, user1_id, user2_card)
        else:
            # Обработка ничьей
            await bot.send_message(user1_id, "‍♂ У вас ничья!")
            await bot.send_message(user2_id, "‍♂ У вас ничья!")
            # Устанавливаем флаг ничьей


            # Не показываем карты при ничьей

        # Обновление состояния игры для следующего раунда
        duel_data[user1_id]["selected_card"] = None
        duel_data[user2_id]["selected_card"] = None
        duel_data[user1_id]["round"] += 1
        duel_data[user2_id]["round"] += 1

        # Проверка на максимальное количество раундов
        if duel_data[user1_id]["round"] > MAX_ROUNDS or duel_data[user2_id]["round"] > MAX_ROUNDS:
            await end_duel(user1_id, user2_id)
        else:
            # Начало следующего раунда
            await start_duel(user1_id, user2_id)

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Ошибка в determine_winner: {e}")

 

